# Angular How to get data from Service Function to Component?

Tags: angular, observable

at the moment I`m learning Angular. Most things working some not. For understanding more I have question. In my Component I got a return from a function wich calls json.
This is my code:

```
total Items: number = 3; //<-- data.total_items needed here

ngOnInit() {
  return this.customerdataService.getCustomersList().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  });
}
```

So far so good, data is shown in my component output. But for pagination I need data inside my CustomerComponent class. Here I have to define totalItems, currentPage and so on. I tried different ways without any result like: data.current_page
Do I have to take this in constructor?

Comment: The best approach in that case would be having a `BaseComponent` which has all pagination stuff info, and extend all your components with BaseComponent where you are using pagination. All pagination stuff would be available in your component rather defining separately in each component.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes only little sense, `ngOnInit` doesn't return anything, nor would it be any helpful since you can't do much with the subscription either.

Observables emit data, and this data will be available during the data callback of `subscribe`.

```
  this.customerdataService.getCustomersList().subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.total_Items = data.total_items; // assignment
    });
```

Comment: How to do better? Got this from youtube tutorial.

Comment: @SaschaK You can put this code inside of your `ngOnInit()`. This is the correct way to assign the returned data from an observable to wherever it's needed in your component.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If I take this code I get Property does not exists on my function?

Comment: Adjust the names to your project, they may be named differently.